# Having DNS Issues when connected to a VPN in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, vpn, dns

I am connecting to a Cisco VPN Server using vpnc. Once connected, my machine was unable to automatically update DNS setting from the new VPN. I tested by temporarily changing /etc/resolv.conf with the proper nameserver and search domain, and everything worked. This is obviously not a long term solution, so I added an additional DNS server and search domain to the VPN settings in Network manager. With those settings in place, resolvconf does add the search domain, but not the DNS IP, and I still cannot do any lookups.

What is my next step in configuring or troubleshooting from here?

Comment: Please file a bug report against resolvconf so that we can debug this together. Use the `apport-bug` command-line utility or use the web interface at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+filebug. Also please read the existing bug #1000244: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1000244

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First make sure that there are no lines beginning with `nameserver` in any files in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d. If /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail is a symbolic link to target `original`, make it point to `/dev/null`.

Second, disconnect from the VPN. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and comment out

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

(i.e., add a `#` so that it looks like the following)

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and then

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Comment: jdthood's answer worked perfect for me in 14.04 too. I also had to remove everything from my /etc/network/interfaces except for the lo reference, and also change managed=false back to true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. I had to reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: Restart networkmanager on Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: Another modern restart method: sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: Looks like this is bug from dnsmasq side? Correct?

Comment: It is amazing to me that this is still a problem in 16.10 after 3 years.

Comment: +1 -- Ubuntu 16.04 - Same issue. Same solution. Thanks

Comment: For me, the final command was: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: If I had more rep, I'd manually award you a bounty

Comment: This worked for me, this has always bugged me when I want to use a VPN to connect to the internet. Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

Try checking if your **/etc/resolv.conf** have symbolic link to **/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf** . It solved the problem for me.

To check if it has symbolic link:

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
```

Sample output, if it has symbolic link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 30 22:22 resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Otherwise, delete or backup existing /etc/resolv.conf and then:

```
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me, thanks!

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, thanks!!

Comment: After a recent `apt upgrade` DNS when connected to my VPN became broken. This symlink was the solution that fixed things for me, thanks! I have also used the accepted answer above when my DNS was patchy (seemed a to come and go when connected to the VPN) so I think these are both good solutions, but apply in slightly different situations.

Comment: Thank you!! Mine was oddly set to `resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` (note the ../)

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 `ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`