# DNS issues with Cisco VPN (vpnc) on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, network-manager, dns, vpn

I'm having issues with DNS resolution of on-network servers.  I can get them directly via IP address, however DNS lookup fails.

Notes:

- I configured the VPN connection via NetworkManager.
- The connection is established correctly and the routes look good, but DNS still fails.
- The configuration is identical to a working configuration on Lubuntu 15.04 where it works flawlessly.  It just won't work in standard Ubuntu.
- My company *does not* use "split tunneling."

Things I have tried in all possible combinations (all have been reverted):

- Disable dnsmasq in NetworkManager.conf
- Manually specify DNS servers / Search in VPN configuration
- Set managed=false in NetworkManager.conf to true (per [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/321850))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that all of our on-network servers are named *.local and this is inherently incompatible with Avahi.  [More reading](http://www.woofpuppy.com/2012/05/solving-local-dns-resolution-problems.html).

The solution I used was to edit /etc/nsswitch.conf and change the following line:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

To:

```
hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```