# Can't configure my pc to use VPN nameserver

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, dns, dnsmasq

I'm on Lubuntu 16.04 and connect to my company's vpn usually via network-manager, nmcli also works for me. But either way I have problems to resolve a internal host by it's name via a browser.

I tried to debug it, but I fail to understand what piece is missing:

```
nslookup my.vpn.host
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
** server can't find my.vpn.host: NXDOMAIN
```

The nameserver of the vpn is at 10.0.0.91 and I added it to the config of the vpn-connection as "Additional nameserver". Also tried adding it to /etc/resolv.conf

However if I do query the nameserver directly it works:

```
nslookup my.vpn.host 10.0.0.91
Server:     10.0.0.91
Address:    10.0.0.91#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my.vpn.host
Address: 10.49.192.31
```

Using `ping my.vpn.host` works too - I assume cause I added name and ip to `/etc/hosts`. But firefox/chrome cannot find the host by it's name, only by it's ip.

I assume I have to add the nameserver yet to another place? This is very frustrating :/

Update:
[image]

Comment: When you query the nameserver directly, are you on the VPN?  Are you using NetworkManager to manage the connections?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes to both questions. Thank you for assisting

Comment: Please screenshot your IPv4 settings screen for that specific network connection you use.  Second question, are you trying to query the VPN nameserver when *not* on the VPN?

Comment: @ThomasWard I added the config screen of the vpn-connection. At the moment it works but I'm really not sure what was it, I followed this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/651945/dns-issues-with-cisco-vpn-vpnc-on-15-04?rq=1 it did not help, I rebooted cause network-manager stopped showing any wifi. Restarting the network-manager did not help either. But after reboot I can access the vpn-host via browser.

Comment: The system uses dnsmasq or something by default, that is what Ubuntu connects to, and then NetworkManager will tell it what nameservers to check (hence the DNS Servers line in your config).  It's possible dnsmasq froze up, and the reboot refreshed it's data.  That also sounds like a NetworkManager problem if it froze up and didn't show wifi connections (or some other networking issue)

Comment: @ThomasWard The wifi list being empty suddenly happens regularly to me. Usually  `service network-manager restart` brings it back, but again not always. So I will try to find out the root cause there. Thank you, appreciate your time!